# как скачать файл с дроп бокса

Tags: python, dropbox

Пытаюсь по данному коду скачать файл с дроп бокса но никак не могу понять где в дроп боксе "Путь к файлу на Dropbox" то есть пример DROPBOX_PATH = '/path/to/your/file',где он этот путь.нигде не могу найти

мой код

```
import dropbox

# Ваш Dropbox API токен
TOKEN = '******'   
access_token='*******'

# Создаем объект Dropbox API
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(access_token)

# Путь к файлу на Dropbox
DROPBOX_PATH = '/test.txt'

# Путь для сохранения скачанного файла на вашем компьютере
DOWNLOAD_PATH = 'D:/Temp/test.txt'

# Скачиваем файл
with open(DOWNLOAD_PATH, 'wb') as f:
    metadata, res = dbx.files_download(path=DROPBOX_PATH)
    f.write(res.content)
```

Comment: Это путь к файлу внутри вашего "диска" Dropbox. Если файл в корне лежит, то будет что-то типа `/file.ext`

Comment: как определить в корне или нет?я создал приложение и теперь там 2 папки.название приложения.папка "приложение" и файл.и не ясно в папке он или нет

Comment: Если файл рядом с папкой, значит он не в папке.

Comment: привел код в посте,по нему вываливается ошибка PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/Temp'   доступ на диск есть.

Comment: Ну так это проблема не дропбокса, у вас или папки Temp на диске D нет, или она есть, а код пытается создать файл в корне диска D с таким же именем, или папки нет, и код пытается создать файл с таким именем, но прав на запись в корень диска нет.

Comment: у меня как у пользователя полные права.Это домашний комп.И папка такая есть по данному пути @ 
insolor

Comment: У вас как у пользователя может и полные права. У программы по умолчанию нет прав на запись в корень диска, если она не под админом запущена.

Comment: Пробуйте добавить имя файла в путь: `DOWNLOAD_PATH = 'D:/Temp/test.txt'`

Comment: да вы правы,добавил файл и создался но пустой и вывалилась ошибка : dropbox.exceptions.BadInputError: BadInputError('2eb267c49262428fb51f7fefaf466648', 'Error in call to API function "files/download": The given OAuth 2 access token is malformed.')  хотя разрешение дал в дроп боксе.сейчас скрин приложу  @ insolor

Comment: разобрался с предыдущей ошибкой которая была связана с разрешением,может кому пригодится На закладке Permissions отметить разрешения files.metadata.read и files.content.read. Но возникла другая dropbox.exceptions.ApiError: ApiError('5a996e7ce8ee433dae16bf6f3a5c40de', DownloadError('path', LookupError('not_found', None))) я так понимаю путь к моему файлу на дропбоксе не верный.Хотя он вроде в корне лежит

Comment: вроде бы перед загрузкой нужно dropbox_connect() выполнить

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем код рабочий для скачивания файлов с дроп бокса.Почему не гугл диск?Пробовал,слишком запутанно и сложно.С дроп боксом проще в разы.Единственное в дроп боксе на закладке Permissions отметить разрешения files.metadata.read и files.content.read и файл на дроп боксе не должен быть в корне.Если вы создали приложение в дропе, то файл должен быть в папке приложения вот так должен выглядеть путь DROPBOX_PATH = '/test.txt' при условии что файл в папке приложения, а не за ее пределами.Причем так DROPBOX_PATH = '/TestovoeApp/test.txt' нельзя.Только так DROPBOX_PATH = '/test.txt', но повторюсь файл не должен быть вне папки приложения  TestovoeApp, он должен быть в ней,в папке TestovoeApp.